# rails api testing json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, unit-testing, active-model-serializers

I have a 4.2.5 rails api and I guess I get this error thanks to the extracted responders. What should I change to make it work?

error:

```
1) Error:
Api::V1::GraphControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
ActionController::UnknownFormat: ActionController::UnknownFormat
    app/controllers/api/v1/graph_controller.rb:7:in `show'
    test/controllers/api/v1/graph_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:GraphControllerTest>'
```

controller

```
class Api::V1::CategoryController < ApplicationController
  def show
    category = params[:category] || "sports"
    @category = Category.where(cat_title: category.capitalize).first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @category, serializer: CategorySerializer, root: "category" }
    end
  end
end
```

Test

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::V1::CategoryControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get show" do 
    get :show, {'category' => 'science'}, format: :json
    assert_response :success
    assert_equal "{\"category\":{\"title\":\"science\",\"sub_categories\":1}}", @response.body
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

```
class Api::V1::CategoryController < ApplicationController
  def show
    category = params[:category] || "sports"
    @category = Category.where(cat_title: category.capitalize).first
    render json: @category, serializer: CategorySerializer, root: "category"
  end
end
```

This way it's working, but the root is not used:

```
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-"{\"category\":{\"title\":\"science\",\"sub_categories\":1}}"
+"{\"title\":\"science\",\"sub_categories\":1}"
```

UPDATE2:

With the following code it doesn't use active model serializer:

```
render json: { category: @category , serializer: CategorySerializer }

-"{\"category\":{\"title\":\"science\",\"sub_categories\":1}}"
+"{\"category\":    {\"cat_id\":2,\"cat_title\":\"Science\",\"cat_pages\":1,\"cat_subcats\":1,\"cat_files\":1,\"created_at\":\"2016-08-06T15:35:29.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2016-08-06T15:35:29.000Z\"},\"serializer\":{}}"
```

Comment: why would you not use this?  render json: {category: @category}

Comment: steady_daddy, I updated my question

Comment: Ahh, I'm an idiot. Closing bracket should be at the end of the line.

Comment: steady_daddy, updated the question again. With the `{ category: @category }` it doesn't use the serializer :(

Comment: Why do you need a serializer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loooks like you made a `http` request, either add the header `Content-Type  = application/json` to request when you call or change your controller code as below to make it working

```
class Api::V1::CategoryController < ApplicationController
  def show
    category = params[:category] || "sports"
    @category = Category.where(cat_title: category.capitalize).first
    render json: { category: @category }
  end
end
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: hgsongra, thx! 2 short questions if you don't mind: 1. Check out my update pls. For some reason the root option is not working. Can you guess the why? 2. Why does it work without respond_to and not with respond_to?

Comment: for question(2) readout [This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)

Comment: `For some reason the root option is not working. Can you guess the why?` will pls elaborate more on this

Comment: Updated my question again

Comment: I am an idiot, closing bracket should be at the end of the line.

Comment: hgsongra, I updated my question once again. If I use `{ category: @category }`, it responds with the original json, not with the one I wanna use with the serializer

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your code that you are using active model serializers incorrectly.
[This Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers) and [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/active-model-serializers-rails-and-json-oh-my/) sitepoint.com article explains how you should properly use serializers in Rails.

Comment: It's weird, that if I use this line `render json: @category, serializer: CategorySerializer, root: "category"` then the serializer is working (except root node), but with this `render json: {category: @category, serializer: CategorySerializer}` it's not.

Comment: Because in the second case the symbol serializer is treated as a key with a value CategorySerializer. render json: {} is JSONifying the data.

Comment: I found the solution. I had to create and initializer and then add this: `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json`